# How Magento Controller-Block-Layout-Templates work together

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, model

How Magento's controller action which is C from **MVC**, **Block-Layout-Template** which is V from MVC and **Collections-Helpers** which is M from MVC work together to show custom data from a mysql table. It's a confusing concept for someone who is new to magento. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have to clear below points to understand well MVC format of Magento how works.

Basic understanding of mvc pattern in magento:

MVC stand for model-view-controller.

**In magento controller acts as C of MVC. All url action management are execute here. This is the entry point for each request.**

Block/Templates/Layout acts as V of MVC pattern.

**All frontend data render and display of content goes here using xml and phtml files with call view files function inside Block.php file.**

Model files acts as  M of MVC pattern.

> All Business related logics for any modules are process here.
>   E.g. CRUD method of module are done here in model file.

**Model files are used to define custom table relations and used for set-get collections. Modules afterSave , beforeSave, afterLoad , beforeLoad logic are defined inside models collection file.**

Just example Customer account save logic are process here plus any customer add,delete or update information logic goes to model file.

*In magento 1 sql folder are used to create database table, upgrade existing table schema.*

**Magento 2**
*Table defination/declaration and table upgrade related data are defined under Setup folder and remove sql folder concept.*

**Helper files in magento are used to define site specific global common functions.**

As per define in above answer link tou can start more MVC patter in details.

Hope this will help you understand MVC pattern in magento.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and its really great help. Can you please describe how I can upgrade existing table schema in my module insidesql->install1.0.0.php

Comment: You can refer more info from here link http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: good explanation! @Rakesh one correction controller is not an entry point of each request <root>/index.php or <root>/pub/index.php or cron.php or shell. [in magento2] +1 :-)

Comment: @Rakesh can you please help me regarding how I can add the custom menu to the top navigation of the frontend. I have tried a lot but its a nightmare now lol. I have two controller actions which I need to display on the top menu. Here is the links:
`**http://127.0.0.1/tandem/oenologist/index/login/**`
`**http://127.0.0.1/tandem/oenologist/index/login/**`

Comment: You can post your questions as new in brief and you getting anser related to your query.

Comment: @Rakesh here is the link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133234/how-to-add-custom-top-menu-navigation-link-not-category

Comment: any comments for the question?

Comment: After accepting answer, you can close this questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is document link for Magento 1.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html

[image]

Comment: can you please check this one. It would be great help:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133234/how-to-add-custom-top-menu-navigation-link-not-category/

Comment: @muditmehrotra first answer is good for you

Comment: I am using the ghot theme for magent and there is no topmenu.phtml file inside the theme folder

Comment: There is top.links.phtml file inside the page/html folder of the theme

Comment: toplink show on top that is not top menu if you want to add there that is easy

Comment: how I can do this

Comment: add in local.xml
`<default>
      <reference name="top.links">

                
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                    <label>Become Service Provider</label>
                    <url>modulefrontname/controllername/action</url>
                    <title>link</title>
                     <prepare>true</prepare>
                <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
                    <position>80</position>
                </action>
                
            </reference>
</default>`

Comment: local.xml inside app/etc/moduel right?

Comment: here `app/design/frontend/namespace/yourtheme/layout/local.xml` kindly learn how to use magneto

Comment: I have added this to local.xml but still nothing happened. Yes i will.

Comment: refresh the cache after that... can you post new question so i can look what you did

Comment: cache refresh also not work...I have already posted a question