# How to add custom top menu navigation link not category

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add custom navigation link in top menu of magento. I have two controller actions which I need to add the top menu of the frontend.

**http://127.0.0.1/tandem/oenologist/ind‌​ex/login/ -> Login**

**http://127.0.0.1/tandem/oenologist/ind‌​ex/list/ -> List**

Its sounds easy but its not in terms of magento. Please, help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an example of adding home link to nav, with active class if you need it

```
<li class="home<?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl()):?> active<?php endif;?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></a></li>
```

this need to be added to topmenu.phtml

Comment: Its not working I am not using rwd default theme. There is top.links.phtml file.

Comment: nothing to do with rwd

Comment: I have put it in top.links.phtml file but noting show in navigation

Comment: page/html/topmenu.phtml

Comment: I have put it in app/design/frontend/base/default/base/default/template/page/topmenu.html

Comment: are you using base template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44524/discussion-between-mudit-mehrotra-and-ahmed-elawadi).

Comment: no I am using a custom theme

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the [documentation](https://themeforest.net/item/mt-ghoster-creative-responsive-magento-theme/11904128) of this theme.

> **Mega Menus built-in** A $100 value that is free when you purchase this
>   theme. Allow you add categories, custom static block (video, banner,
>   links..), CMS to the navigation

They are using MegaMenu extension, there must be some settings in admin panel to manage all navigation menus/links.

Comment: Its ghost theme from the theme forest http://mt-ghost04.magentothemes.net/

How I can do this. Its really urgent to add these to links in top navigation.

Comment: I have not seen it's admin panel. Try to find it yourself.

Comment: There is no option to manage the menu

Comment: Go to admin, `Catalog > Manage Category`, edit any category, then try to find Mega Menu. There may be an option for this (just guessing).

Comment: nothing is there, I am also new to this theme. I have added an category but its also not showing in the menu.

Comment: check `/app/etc/modules`, is there any extension, named MegaMenu or something ?

Comment: no there is nothing

Comment: Then only solution is to contact theme provider, and ask him, where is  MegaMenu and how to manage navigation ?

Comment: yeah as there is no topmenu.phtml